# Convert String that already in binary to binary python

Tags: python, binary, converters

I already have a list that contain some string (as output of other process) as,
(example)

```
BitStream = ['011000111001', '100100111001', '100101100110', ...]
```

Now i need to get the actual value as binary, not as string
But when i try to change it to binary with

```
for bit in BitStream:
    BitInteger = bin(bit)
```

But it give me error message as str object cannot be interpreted as an index
But when i try to make change it as int first, and i change it to binary,

```
for bit in BitStream:
    BitInteger = int(bit)
    BitIntegerBin = bin(BitInteger)
```

The binary value is not the actual value in the string. But the value of actual binary that treated as integer that changed to binary.
How do i get the actual value?

Comment: you want integer value of that binary???

Comment: ...what? Could you show some expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: Already done...
Btw the expected output is the string value itself. But not as str, but as bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear but what i understand:

```
>>> a
'011000111001'
>>> bin(int(a,2))
'0b11000111001'      # python valid binary format
>>> int(a,2)         # integer
1593
```

for your code integer and binary:

```
>>> BitStream = ['011000111001', '100100111001', '100101100110']
>>> [ [int(x,2),bin(int(x,2))] for x in BitStream ]
[[1593, '0b11000111001'], [2361, '0b100100111001'], [2406, '0b100101100110']]
```

Comment: Thanks. It really do the magic. Only give ,2 in the back lol xD